# With odd $\ n>9, \sigma(n) < {11\over 16} e^{\gamma} n \log \log n $?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

If that's not the case, do we know anyway some upper bound better than that given by Robin's inequality, since it has been shown that it holds for all odd numbers > 9 ( [Choie, YoungJu, et al. "On Robin’s criterion for the Riemann hypothesis." Journal de Théorie des Nombres de Bordeaux 19.2 (2007): 357-372, Theorem 1.2](http://jtnb.cedram.org/cedram-bin/article/JTNB_2007__19_2_357_0.pdf))? The condition $\ n>9 $ is not necessary, I really care only about the bound.
I'd be grateful if you could give me a proof, too.

Comment: Do you know of [Robins theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RobinsTheorem.html) which is the same as you say for all $n$ and without the $\frac{11}{16}$ factor. This statement is shown to be equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis making this a pretty pretty pretty advanced question to just 'ask for a proof'.

Comment: @Winther Do you know that it has been shown that Robin's inequality holds for all odd numbers > 9 ?

Comment: I guess I better add this in the details.

Comment: No. Such a proof would probably be both advanced and long. I think you would be better of going directly to the paper that proves this.

Comment: Not really, you can check, I've just cited the paper in the details.
And after all, it was fairly obvious that no odd number > 5040 would have violated RI, which is why I'm asking if a better bound is known.

Comment: @Will
Thank you, but that can't really give me a proof, can it? In fact, since I don't need this for mere curiosity, I'd like one, but I guess there's none, even considering what Dietrich said (though I still don't get it).

Comment: @WillJagy
Alright then. Just another thing: is what Dietrich (who now seems to be offline) said true? I can't quite understand.

Comment: @almagest You are right, they indeed prove Robin's inequality for all odd numbers $n>9$. Theorem $1.5$ only shows this for $5$-free integers, though. So I was not completely sure. Still, I don't see why the inequality of the OP should be true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Obviously it isn't implied by that result. Simply I needed a better bound for odd numbers, but I managed to achieve the result I was looking for without it.