# Who should I ask for Robin's paper? At any rate, I want to find out if a similar result to his can be achieved with 36 instead of 12.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, online-resources, divisor-sum

Robin proved unconditionally that for $\ n \ge 3$ , $$ \sigma(n)<\left(e^\gamma+{\log\log12\left({\frac73}-e^\gamma \log\log12\right)\over (\log \log n)^2}\right)n \log \log n. $$
I need a similar result with$\ 36 $, but unfortunately there's no trace of the original paper online. It is reference 9 at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number

Comment: Do you have a citation for the paper in question?  If not, do you have a citation for the paper where you learned about the result?

Comment: Which of the 12s do you hope to replace?

Comment: Here is another one, maybe more elementary http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.5078.pdf&embedded=true

Comment: @almagest The paper you have cited was already cited by the OP - see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920559/with-odd-n9-sigman-11-over-16-e-gamma-n-log-log-n.

Comment: @Burde I don't understand your point. He is asking where he can get papers, not references to MSE

Comment: I have the original paper. What do you actually want to do with it? For one thing, you did not type the above correctly, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79927/which-n-maximize-gn-frac-sigmann-log-log-n

Comment: @almagest The OP *himself* cited this paper already there, and you commented his question about this very paper.

Comment: @Burde. I have deleted that comment. But I thought the usual rule was that the questioner searched to make sure the question had not been asked before. Life would be impossible if everyone commenting or answering had to check past questions to see if the questioner might already know something! :)

Comment: @Charles I meant to replace both 12s, but I've just realized the second would be enough.

Comment: @WillJagy I know the condition is $\ n \ge 13 $ , but with some easy calculations one can easily verify it hold for $\ n \ge 3 $ (at least, now I have to go and I can't recheck, but I did and I think it does hold for $\ n \ge 3 $ ). I'm approaching Robin's inequality and succeeding in replacing the second 12 is what I need for something I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems appropriate to put the first two pages as a preview. For small $n,$ Ramanujan's method gives much better bounds, the easiest are
$$ \sigma(n) \leq 3 \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)^{3/2},    $$
$$ \sigma(n) \leq 12 \left( \frac{n}{6} \right)^{5/4},    $$
$$ \sigma(n) \leq 28 \left( \frac{n}{12} \right)^{7/6}.    $$
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you! Unluckily Ramanujan's bounds aren't appropriate for my intentions, since I'm looking for something which holds for any value after some $\ m $. Whereas I was wondering if you could let me have the proof of Theorem 2, it'd be of great help.

Comment: @numb, the proofs are not split up, they are side by side. I do not expect  SE or the moderators to object to a two page preview, but I cannot put the whole paper here.

Comment: Then, is it against the rules to give you my email?

Comment: @numb, That's fine, but it is better to email me at my gmail address without either of us posting addresses here, look up with my last name at http://www.ams.org/cml